# How to add icons to a menu?

Tags: theming, 8

I use Drupal 8.

I would simply want to add icons to one of the menus with a `<span>`.

Have you runways?

Comment: Can you specify the HTML structure you are after? Do you want the <span> tag inside the <a> tag or inside the <li> tag? I have some code for this structure: <ul><li><span></span><a>Link Text</a></li></ul>. Let me know if that is what you are after. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Rick, the html structure : basically : <ul><li><a><span>Link Text</span></a></li>

Comment: In that case I will agree with the answer from Ivan. In order to modify the <a> tag the I would add the <span> via the preprocess_links() function.

Comment: Hi Rick, can you propose a solution? That of Ivan in spite of my numerous tries and the hours crossed to try to run it does not work...

Comment: Ok, I will need to try and test some code. As soon as I get a chance I will post some code.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'm doing it for dropdown operations(Font Awesome icons).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_links().
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_links(array &$variables) {
  if (stripos($variables['theme_hook_original'], 'links__dropbutton__operations') === 0) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'menu';
    $links = &$variables['links'];
    foreach ($links AS $key => &$link) {
      switch (Html::getClass($key)) {
        case 'view';
        case 'canonical':
          $icon = 'eye';
          break;

        case 'edit':
          $icon = 'pencil';
          break;

        case 'delete':
          $icon = 'trash';
          break;

        case 'clone':
          $icon = 'clone';
          break;

        case 'add':
        case 'create':
        $icon = 'plus';
          break;

        case 'manage-fields':
          $icon = 'list';
          break;

        case 'manage-form-display':
          $icon = 'server';
          break;

        case 'manage-display':
          $icon = 'th';
          break;

        case 'devel':
          $icon = 'code';
          break;

        case 'pay':
          $icon = 'money';
          break;

        case 'enable':
          $icon = 'toggle-off';
          break;

        case 'disable':
          $icon = 'toggle-on';
          break;

        default:
          $icon = 'question';
          break;
      }

      $link['link']['#title'] = [
        '#type' => 'inline_template',
        '#template' => '<i class="fa fa-{{ icon }}" title="{{ title }}"></i><span class="visually-hidden">{{ title }}</span>',
        '#context' => [
          'title' => $link['link']['#title'],
          'icon' => $icon
        ]
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yvan, in Drupal 8 the preprocess functions are always used? I had understood that it was not any more the best way to modify the template.

Comment: No changes in this regard from D7. Sometimes you can use template, sometimes preprocessor is better. It depends on the use case.

Comment: Ok, to adapt your solution to an item of a simple menu (not of dropdown), how I do have to make? For example the user menu? I made out a will but it does not work for the moment

Comment: I try `if (stripos($variables['theme_hook_original'], 'menu__account') === 0) {` or `if ($variables['theme_hook_original'] == 'menu__account') {` but doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

There is a new easy alternative to display icons in Menu Items in Drupal 8:

[The Menu Manipulator module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_manipulator) now provides an option for you to create a list of available icons that editors can select when editing menu links.

[image]

The icon's ID is then passed to Twig so you can theme/render/display it however you want (e.g. an icon font such as FontAwesome, a custom Twig file, as a background image in CSS ...etc).

Example `yourtheme/templates/menus/menu--main.html.twig`:

```
[...]
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('menu-item', 'column') }}>
        {% if item.icon %}
             {# Assuming you use so type of icon font #}
             <span class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></span>

             {# Assuming your icons are callable as Twig file. #}  
             {% include '@yourtheme/icons/icon.html.twig' with { icon: item.icon } %}
        {% endif %}
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how the [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) add the body field or you can use the body field abd insert image with the CKEditor.